# inheriting a class from a partial specialization of a template class

Tags: c++

I have a templated class named check and its partial specialization, now i am publically inheriting a class named childcheck from the partial specialization of the class check. but compiler gives following error message
**no matching function for call to `check::check()' 

candidates are: check::check(const check&) 

check::check(t*) [with t = int*]** 

look at the code and explain the reason please

```
#include<iostream.h>
template<class t>
class check
{
t object;
public:
check(t);
};
//defining the constructor
template<class t>
check<t>::check<t>(t element)
{
cout<<"general templated class constructor"<<endl;
}



//partial specialization
template<class t>
class check<t*>
{
t* object;
public:
check(t*);
};
template<class t>
check<t*>::check<t*>(t* element)
{
cout<<"partial specialization constructor"<<endl;
}



//childcheck class which is derived from the partial specialization
template<class t>
class childcheck:public check<t*>//inheriting from the partial specialization
{
t object;
public:
childcheck(t);
};
template<class t>
childcheck<t>::childcheck<t>(t element):check<t>(element)
{
cout<<"child class constructor"<<endl;
}



main()
{
int x=2;
int*ptr=&x;
childcheck<int*>object(ptr);
cout<<endl;
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You should indent your code. It is also conventional to use uppercase first letter for typenames that are template arguments.

Comment: ok, if i pass t* to check then still compiler gives the same error

Comment: shouldn't this have the `homework` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You inherit from `check<t*>` yet call a base class constructor `check<t>` as if you inherited from `check<t>`.  Which `check<>` do you want to inherit from?

I believe that what you really want do is this:

```
template<class t> 
class childcheck:public check<t>
```

If `t` is `int*`, then `childcheck<int*>` will inherit from `check<int*>` which is fine.  The rest of your code can remain the way it is in the original question.

Read about [Template Partial Specialization at cprogramming.com](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html), it explains 
your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346533/partial-specialization-of-template-class-issue).

Comment: no sir i want to inherit from the partial specialization. what is wrong with the provided code please explain

Comment: if i write childcheck<t>::childcheck<t>(t element):check<t*>(element) compiler still gives the same error message

Comment: you'd need to write `.... ):check<t*>(&element)` which could be bad for different reasons... do you intend to keep a copy of `element` in your `childcheck<t>` instance?

Comment: why i should write this , element is already a pointer and a pointer can receive a pointer why i should wirte this?

Comment: Because in your example, `childcheck<int*>` inherits from `check<int**>`, so `check<int**>::check` expects an `int**` param but gets `int*`. If that's OK with you you must explicitly cast, otherwise change you definition so `childcheck<int*>` inherits from `check<int*>`, that is, `childcheck<T>` inherits from `check<T>`

Comment: ok i understood your point, but i am still confused because i posted a question about partial specialization here and a person answers me look at the selected answer on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346533/partial-specialization-of-template-class-issue and then comment about this answer